# Artifactory repo structure organization

Tags: naming-conventions, artifactory, enterprise

Artifactory has a strong opinion on naming convention. They have a good write up here (https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/) but it leaves many open questions.

This question is specific to how to structure local, remote and virtual repos when there are multiple teams (greater than 50) while considering security, performance and operability. How do you organize your repos to allow teams to promote in their own cycle and publish to a central repo in case they want to publish a reusable component?